# backbone- go through collection, and render in correct order?

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, collections, view

How to be sure that all of the view-s will be displayed in correct order. because of use of Ajax, first one finished will be displayed first, i want to always be displayed in right order...

```
_.each(view.collection.models, function (category) {
   var productBlockListView = new ProductBlockListView({model: category});
   productBlockListView.setElement(view.el).render();
}, this);
```

Comment: What do you mean? You're not fetching the entire collection at once? And `setElement(view.el)` is madness that will make a mess of your event handling, why don't your views have their own `el`s? Don't `_.each(view.collection.models, ...)` when you can `view.collection.each(...)`. Why isn't `view` handling rendering its own collection?

Comment: What should I use instead of setElement? Why is better to use view.collection.each(...), instead of _.each(view.collection.models, ...)? Thanks a lot fro your response.

Comment: Don't share `el`s at all, let each view have its own distinct `el` and then the parent can put them on the page where they're supposed to go. Using `collection.each(...)` is better than `_.each(collection.models, ...)` because you should avoid messing around with something's internals, use the provided interfaces whenever possible.

Comment: Problem is that, el is dynamic. I could in this example do this var customEL = "#product-block-list-" + view.model.get("id"); var productBlockView = new ProductBlockView({model: product, renderEl:customEL }); and then every product go to right parent. But i have problem they finish rendering in diferent time, and they dont display in right order, what can i do to prevent this, order in collection is ok, but when they render they are mixed up :(

Comment: But they'll render in the same order as they are in the collection. Can you provide a functioning demo of the problem on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Comment: i can't, it is too complex. App use API, and sessionID. I checked now, i did console.log collection, and every pass for every model; and order is ok, but display is not in that order. This killing me :(

Answer (score 0):

Use a `comparator` option to get a sorted collection.

```
var items = new Backbone.Collection([{
    firstName: 'Steve',
    lastName: 'Jobs'
}, {
    firstName: 'Bill',
    lastName: 'Gates'
}], {comparator: 'firstName'});

items.each(function(item) {
    console.log('%s %s', item.get('firstName'), item.get('lastName'));
});
```

**[Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator)**
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/n30n5mpm/)**

Comment: My collection is in right order, but it is not rendered in that order.

Comment: Maybe your `.render()` method is asynchronous? In this way you should try to use promises to render views one by one.